# Get accesToken from facebook app AIR Mobile ( com.facebook.graph.FacebookMobile )

Tags: android, facebook, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api, air

I've seen in may apps that if you're logged in with facebook app, you will instantly post on facebook without to go through the login process 
I'm using  *com.facebook.graph.FacebookMobile* , but as for now i couldn't find a way to get the accessToken from facebook app. 
When i install it, i have to login inside it before posting on my wall.

Does anyone know any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the native Share Dialog. Documentation is here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share-dialog/ and it requires the Facebook SDK for Android.

Comment: Is there an ane that will help me integrate this in as3?